# display sqlite in listview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I want to display my `Sqlite` data into my `ListView` but I can't do it.

Now it can show a `Toast` but how can I run it into my `ListView`?

Thank you.

```
public class fehrest extends Activity {
    public String fonts="BNazanin.ttf";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // DATABASE START
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        try {
            String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases";
            File f = new File(destPath);
            if (!f.exists()) {              
                f.mkdirs();
                f.createNewFile();

                //---copy the db from the assets folder into 
                // the databases folder---
                CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("mydb"),
                    new FileOutputStream(destPath + "/MyDB"));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //---get all contacts---
        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                DisplayContact(c);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();

        //DATABASE END

        setFace();
        //Tab2 contents
        }

        //DATABASE COPY FILES

        public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, 
                    OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
            //---copy 1K bytes at a time---
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        }

        // DATABASE COPY FILES END

        // DATABASE SHOW INFO
        public void DisplayContact(Cursor c) {

            Toast.makeText(this,
                "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
                "Name: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                "Email:  " + c.getString(2),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // DATABASE SHOW INFO END
```

Comment: read android notepad tutorial

Comment: did you try the suggestion in my post. Does it work??

Comment: sorry , but it dosent work

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below. You can also a CustomAdapter. For the example i used a `SimpleAdapter`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html

```
    ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    //listview in main.xml
    String[] from = new String[] {"id", "name", "email"};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3};
    List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();
     if(c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  
            String id =  c.getString(0);
            String name= c.getString(1);
            String email = c.getString(2);   
            map.put("id",id);
            map.put("name",name);
            map.put("email",email); 
            fillMaps.add(map); 
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();

    } 

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.mylayout, from, to);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

mylayout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can also use a Cursor Adapter which is probably more appropriate in this case

```
  String[] from = new String[] {"id", "name", "email"}; // columns
  int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3}; 
  SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.mylayout, c, from, to);
```

Note:

`SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)`

This constructor was deprecated in API level 11. This option is discouraged, as it results in Cursor queries being performed on the application's UI thread and thus can cause poor responsiveness or even Application Not Responding errors. As an alternative, use `LoaderManager` with a `CursorLoader`.

Comment: this is not how sqlitedb data should be handled, here CursorAdapter (or rather one of its derived class) is the obvious class to be used

Comment: @pskink yes you can use a Cursor Adapter or a Custom adapter. i just showed how its done with an example